# 'Import dataset' function in Rstudio stopped working

Tags: database, dataframe, import, rstudio

When I click on 'Import dataset' function in the upper right corner of Rstudio, I get this:

[image]

I use this function and that particular dataset every day, and such an error never showed up before.

Simple restarting PC didn't work.

Updating Rstudio to the newest version also.

Any suggestions guys on why it might have happened and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that you have an out-dated version of the `rlang` package installed on your computer. If you run `install.packages("rlang")` in the R console in RStudio, it will install an updated version. Once you've restarted R, you should find it works as normal.

Comment: simple and smart, it worked) actually I thought that 'rlang' is already installed in my Rstudio, because as I said above I use that function and that dataset every day, and never got this error before